# Add a tag to multiple items dynamically unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags

I have problem with add dynamically `tag` to `gameObejcts` , when I `Instantiate` an `enemy` I add enemy tag using this:

```
GameObject temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemy, spwanPosition, spwanRotation);
temp.gameObject.tag = "Enemy";
```

I read this from  : [Is it possible create a tag programmatically](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/33597/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tag-programmatically.html)

but when I try to Destroy this object with specific `explosion` There is no object with `Enemy` tag:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Boundary")
    {
        return;
    }
    if (other.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Debug.Log("enemy");   # Never printed in console
        Instantiate(enemyExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
    }
    Instantiate(explosion, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

How can I add a tag dynamically to a `gameObject` that `Instantiate` multiple times?

**Edit**

This is the Picture from Instantiated enemy Object in Paused game , It is so wired , it has `Enemy tag` , But why this didn't work?

[image]

The problem is when in run-time `Enemy` tag is assigned to objects but when I check `if(other.tag == "Enemy")` this dosen't work!

Comment: I'm confused. You say the Instantiated object has no tag, but then you say it does have a tag...?

Comment: Tag says Enemy. Name says Enemy(Clone). Layer says Default. Which is wrong according to your expectations?

Comment: @fafase , I `Instantiate` alot of them , It names them Clone by him self, I dont know waht id Layer

Comment: I don't get it (and I might not be the only one), it tags Enemy and this is an instantiated object because of the Clone extension. What are you after? Tell us what you want to do coz right now, you seem to be trying to do something you say is already done.

Comment: @Arman, changing your question is **NOT** a good thing. The question was about the renaming a  tag which I provided a solution on how to properly change. You said it didn't work but then you went ahead and replaced the original code with my code. The picture I asked you to upload proves that the tag is changed is now changed to enemy. When your original question is answered, you accept it and then ask for a new question if you are having a different problem. It looks like you are now having a collision problem. Don't change your question! Ask another one. If you want to show your new code,

Comment: you put the new code in the **EDIT** but don't replace the original one.

Comment: It added a tag , but it didnt work in other.tag == Enemy , this the problem

Answer (score 1):

The link that you posted is about creating tags dynamically, you don't need this and I don't see why anyone would need to do this.

I presume you have a tag named Enemy in the tag manager?

You are instantiating an enemy prefab, which means you don't need `enemy.tag = "Enemy"`. Just set the enemy prefab tag to Enemy in the inspector.

This will instantiate the new enemies with the same values as the prefab.

As for the trigger not working, I am not sure, make sure you have met all the specifications for the enemy calling the OnTriggerEnter().

Taken from http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/753481/ontriggerenter-not-working-tried-everything-c.html

> OnTriggerEnter, at least one of them has to have the Is Trigger property checked and at least one of them has to have a Rigid Body. If neither of your objects is a Trigger, you can use OnCollisionEnter instead.
>
> Once that's all set, you should check the Layers (not Tags) on your objects. To edit which Layers collide with each other, you can look at Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics.

Answer (score 0):

> I read this from : Is it possible create a tag programmatically

It is **NOT** possible to create a tag during run-time. You can **change** the tag of a GameObject to an **existing** one but you **CANNOT** create a **new** one.

So **before** you **assign** a tag named `Enemy` or `Boundary`, make sure that you have already created such tag in the **Editor** first. It is also **case-sensitive**.

> I have problem with add dynamically tag to gameObejcts , when I
>   Instantiate an enemy I add enemy tag using this:
>
> ```
> Instantiate(enemy, spwanPosition, spwanRotation);
> enemy.tag = "Enemy";
> ```
>
> How can I add a tag dynamically to a gameObject that Instantiate
>   multiple times?

That's wrong. What you are doing now is **changing** the tag of the **original** GameObject **NOT** the Instantiated **GameObject**. To **change** the **tag** of the **Instantiated** GameObject, **store** a reference of the **Instantiated** GameObject and then **modify** the **tag**. The code below is what you are looking for.

```
GameObject tempGOB= (GameObject)Instantiate(enemy, spwanPosition, spwanRotation);
tempGOB.tag = "Enemy"; //Change the tag of the Instantiated GameObject instead of the enemy(original object)
```

Comment: It should work. Instantiate a game object, select the GameObject in your scene then post a screenshot of your screen.

Comment: Picture added , it so strange !

Comment: From the picture you uploaded it works. It changes the tag to "Enemy". Look closer where it says Tag, it successfully set the tag to Enemy. Isn't that what you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that your problem is not the tag, but the collision. Does your enemy object have a collider? Does a simple collision test succeed?

Edit (forget about this):

Actually your problem might be that you shouldn't use `other.tag` but `other.gameObject.tag`.

Comment: I would have thought `other.tag` would be the same as `other.gameObject.tag`. There is only a tag for the gameobject, not colliders.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at it and it is the same.

Comment: `Other.gameObject.tag` is didn't work too! and enemy has a `Collison Mesh`

Comment: @Arman Have you marked your mesh collider as `IsConvex` and `IsTrigger` in the inspector?

Mesh colliders only detect collisions if they are marked as Convex.

Comment: Yes I did , its istrigger and isconvex